# There was a red line showing expression must be a modifiable lvalue error under the struct of array line

Tags: c++

DATA forex[] is my struct of array. I'm trying to assign the answer of the equation (price/time_frame) into my forex[i].SMA. time_frame is another value that i got through user input from another function that i did not show here. But there was an error that i do not understand. There was a red line showing expression must be a modifiable lvalue error under the forex[i].SMA

```
void calculate_SMA(int time_frame, int count, DATA forex[])
{
    double sma, price_total;
    for (int j = time_frame - 1; j < count; j++)
    {
        price_total = 0.0;

        for (int i = 0; i < i + time_frame; i++)
            price_total += forex[i].price;

        forex[j].SMA = price_total / time_frame;
        cout << forex[j].SMA << endl;
    }
}
```

this is the typedef struct

```
typedef struct
{
    char date[11];
    double price;
    double SMA;
    double EMA;
}DATA;
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213692/discussion-on-question-by-ying-shuang-there-was-a-red-line-showing-expression-mu).